# generating unique CHAR(8) random values in an SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:
`-id : primary key

-code : CHAR(8) unique`

Is there a way in ANSI SQL (or MySQL) of generating a unique numeric *code* ( *can*  be  based on the autonumeric *id* ) in a single SQL statement for any number of rows? (let's say 100)

I'm already doing this in a loop in PHP but wonder if it can be done in pure SQL.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just use the id and append some character to fill out to 8?

Comment: Yes, it can't be sequential, so users can't guess it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the current requirements:

```
SELECT floor(rand() * 90000000) + 10000000; # Will create an eight-digit random number
INSERT INTO table (code) VALUES (floor(rand() * 90000000) + 10000000);
UPDATE table SET code = floor(rand() * 90000000) + 10000000;
```

---

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( MD5( RAND( ) ), 25 )
```

Alternatively based on the auto-increment:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( MD5(id), 25 ) FROM table
```

Or to update it:

```
UPDATE table SET code = SUBSTRING( MD5(id), 25 )
```

Comment: @Mchl Of course this it not unique, nothing that fits into 8;9;10… chars can be unique…

Comment: Sorry, by generating, I meant Inserting it into the table.

Comment: @Mchl And what if you try to fit a 9 digit number into an 8 digit field? :)

Comment: @Petruza Use my last snippet, this will update each row. Otherwise simply insert `SUBSTRING( MD5( RAND( ) ), 25 )` as one value.

Comment: Then I come up with some other idea, like translating the PK to hexadecimal notation.

Comment: @Mchl "Yes, it can't be sequential, so users can't guess it.", quote from a question's comment

Comment: @Petruza Why this all new requirements? Why don't you ask the right question in the first place? Why do you use a char for numerics?

Comment: That complicates things a little, but not by much. We could still create a bijective function in that range, that would convert integes to strings.

Comment: @TimWolla: because I forgot to write it in the first place.

Comment: @Petruza But why the char-datatype?

Comment: @Petruza I updated my answer to include a method to create an eight-digit random number

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code

```
select substr(UUID(), 1, 8)
```